# $SU(N)$ subalgebras and Dynkin diagrams?

Tags: group-theory, lie-algebra

Reading [this paper](https://www.itp.uni-hannover.de/fileadmin/arbeitsgruppen/ag_flohr/lectures/symm/sose10-ho8.pdf) (Handout VIII for the course  SYMMETRIES IN PHYSICS, Michael Flohr, Subgroups and Unified Theories), I had my ideas confused: it is said that we can take any $SU(N)$ with its related Dynkin diagram, separate the last dot from the whole diagram and obtain two diagrams made of $N-2$ dots and $1$ dot respectively. So my questions. Am I right thinking that:

1. I can associate an $SU(2)$ algebra to that single dot.
2. As a consequence I can write that $su(3) \supset su(2)\oplus su(2)$. Note that $su(3)$ Dynkin diagram has two dots, then two $su(2)$ algebras.
3. Why instead that single dot is always associated with an $U(1)$ algebra? For example $SU(5)\rightarrow SU(3)\times SU(2) \times U(1)$.

Comment: I think you may be conflicting extended and unextended Dykin diagrams here. A single dot is the unextended diagram of SU(2), but the extended diagram has two dots (and four edges, if memory serves me right). The extended diagram of SU(N) has N dots, forming a circle. Dynkin's method of maximal subalgebras involves both extended and unextended diagrams. You may want to read about this method in a more specific source, a book on simple Lie algebras.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification. Do you think the paper i linked talks about extended Dynkin diagrams?

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v2): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of link, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of link rot.

Answer (score 0):

Studying more in detail the subject I figured out the problem. Considering $SU(3)$, it is true that we can find two subgroups (both of them are $SU(2)$) that are contained in it. This of course doesn't mean that $SU(3)=SU(2)\otimes SU(2)$, the two subgroups may overlap. $U(1)$ came out from that dot that we left out as it only needs a diagonal generator and no additionals creation-annihilation operators that may be already included in some other subgroup.